# jquery menu repeating animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm using a jQuery menu I found online, and I've managed to style it and fill it in right, but the animation for the dropdown keeps repeating. I've read about .stopPropagation() but that doesn't seem to be working... You can try hovering over the 'types of insurance' link a couple of times here: http://jsfiddle.net/rPGaE/ to see what I mean. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the menu drop down action is triggered by the whole "dropMe" class. This means that when the menu items drop down, they are part of the  "dropMe" class and can retrigger the drop down animation. I changed the class of the link its own class called "dropLink" which is the class which can trigger the drop down. It helps with the repeating animations.
An example of this is at: http://jsfiddle.net/rPGaE/5/